# cmake: contains unsupported character when I try to install sfml via terminal

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake, sfml

cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE

taken from [this](http://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/building-sfml-2-0-with-make-for-gcc/) site.

does not work when I cd into the folder I get this: CMake Error:
  The path to the source directory:

```
/home/hassooni/Development/sfml/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE
```

contains unsupported character '='.

Please use a different source directory name.

Please help!

Thanks

note: I want to use it with g++ and gvim, I have all the dependencies and have done everything specified by the linked tutorial! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have spaces between the D and the variable in your declarations. It should be:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE
```

note, the spaces between `-D` and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` and `-D` and `BUILD_SHARD_LIBS=TRUE` have been removed.